# Как отобразить прогресс скачивания файла инициированный ajax запросом?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, браузер, rest

Пытаюсь показать прогресс скачивания файла с сервера, для этого я вынес следующий код в *директиву*:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('downloadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.disabled = false;
  let ctrl = this;
  ctrl.download = function(response) {
    let file = response.data;
    let fileName = response.headers('Content-Disposition').match(/filename(?:(?:\*=UTF-8'')|(?:=))(.*)/)[1];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadstart = () => {
      $scope.apply(function() {
        $scope.disabled = true;
      });
    };
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], {
        type: file.type
      });
      let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = decodeURI(fileName.replace(/[\"]/gi, ''));
      a.href = objectUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.disabled = false;
        });
      }, 2000);
    };
    fileReader.onprogress = data => {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.lengthComputable) {
        let progress = parseInt(((data.loaded / data.total) * 100), 10);
        console.log(progress);
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          $scope.progress = progress;
        });
      }
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
});

app.directive('download', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'download.html',
    scope: {},
    controller: 'downloadCtrl',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      element.on('click', function(){
        let url = 'https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/archive/master.zip';
        console.log(url);
        $http.get(url).then(response => {
          console.log(response);
          controller.download(response); });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.btn > .progress {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="download.html">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="disabled">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ng-hide="disabled"></span>
        <span uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active" value="progress" ng-show="disabled"></span>
      </button>
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <download></download>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Данный код работает, но, с одним *небольшим* недостатком: открываем консоль разработчика и смотрим процесс выполнения:

1. Запрос на сервер на получения файла находится в режиме ожидания.
2. Получен ответ от сервера, в консоли разработчика видно что идет процесс получения файла(прогресс бар еще не виден)
3. При достижении прогресса в 50..75%(*на глазок, из консоли разработчика*), появляется прогресс бар, дальше все работает корректно.

Добавил в обработчик события `onprogress` вывод в консоль, после того как файл получен, в консоли появляются значение прогресса: 12,17,31,45,59,74,78,92,100

Подскажите что я делаю не так, почему прогресс бар отображается не сразу после начала скачивания файла?

P.S.: поведение повторяется в последних версиях Firefox & Chrome

Comment: `value="progress"`, странно что вообще срабатывает. Отредактируйте пример, чтобы можно было воспроизвести. `.btn > .progress` ни к кому не прицепится в этом коде.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev что бы воспроизвести необходимо отправить ajax запрос на файл, к сожалению у меня не получилось заставить снипет выполнить такой запрос, в вопрос добавил реализацию метода `onload`. *.btn > .progress ни к кому не прицепится в этом коде.* - вы можете проверить открыв снипет на редактирование и запустив на выполнение изменяя значение `disabled` в контроллере

Comment: Может быть я немного не в теме... Но где у вас событие скачивания файла? Я вижу только событие `onprogress` у `FileReader`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko у `FileReader` есть события `onloadstart`, `onload`, `onprogress` исходя из которых я и строю свою логику

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, с помощью `FileReader` вы сохраняете данные в браузере. Т.е. эти события происходят когда файл **уже получен от сервера**. В вопросе же говорится про прогресс скачивания файла. И вот собственно прогресса скачивания я и не вижу.

Comment: У вас ошибка в скрипте `apply` - такой функции нету у `$scope`. У вас браузер не показывает ошибки?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko [$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66704/discussion-between-bald-and-stepan-kasyanenko).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимо, у вас проблема где-то в другом месте.

Потому что в принципе все работает хорошо. Обратите внимание, `fileReader.onprogress` не должен выполняться для каждого процента. Он выполняется тогда, когда приходит порция данных. Если размер данных не большой, то он вообще может вызваться 2 раза, например.

Также добавил пример события скачивания файла с сервера.

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/t61mdqoj/).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('downloadCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.disabled = false;
  let ctrl = this;
  $scope.progress = 0;

  function myApply() {// Грязный хак. Почему то в мозиле fileReader.onloadstart выполняется в $digest цикле
    if ($scope.$$phase || $scope.$root.$$phase)
      return;
    $scope.$apply();
  }
  ctrl.setProgress = function(event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
      let progress = parseInt(((event.loaded / event.total) * 100), 10);
      $scope.disabled = true;
      $scope.progress = progress;
      myApply();
    }
  };
  ctrl.download = function(response) {
    let file = new Blob([response.data]);
    //let fileName = response.headers('Content-Disposition').match(/filename(?:(?:\*=UTF-8'')|(?:=))(.*)/)[1];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onloadstart = function() {
      console.log("file starting load");
      $scope.progress = 0;
      $scope.disabled = true;
      myApply();
    };
    fileReader.onload = function() {
      console.log("file loaded");
      let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], {
        type: file.type
      });
      let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.download = decodeURI("test.pdf");
      a.href = objectUrl;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      setTimeout(function() {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
        $scope.disabled = false;
        $scope.progress = 0;
        console.log('file downloaded');
        myApply();
      }, 2000);
    };
    fileReader.onprogress = function(event) {
      console.log("file loading", event);
      ctrl.setProgress(event);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  };
});
app.decorator("$xhrFactory", [
  "$delegate", "$injector",
  function($delegate, $injector) {
    return function(method, url) {
      var xhr = $delegate(method, url);
      var $http = $injector.get("$http");
      var callConfig = $http.pendingRequests[$http.pendingRequests.length - 1];
      if (angular.isFunction(callConfig.onProgress))
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", callConfig.onProgress);
      return xhr;
    };
  }
])
app.directive('download', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    template: `<button class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="disabled">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt" ng-hide="disabled"></span>
        <span uib-progressbar class="progress-striped active" value="progress" ng-show="disabled"></span>
      </button>`,
    scope: {},
    controller: 'downloadCtrl',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        let url = 'https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/asp.net_mvc_tutorial.pdf';
        $http({
          method: "GET",
          url: url,
          onProgress: function(e) {
            console.log("file recieving", e);
            controller.setProgress(e);
          },
        }).then(response => {
          console.log("file recieved");
          controller.download(response);
        });
      })
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.btn>.progress {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-touch.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/gh-pages/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <download></download>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```